# Interpolation inside ngStyle background Image

Tags: angular, background-image, string-interpolation, ng-style

I've looked around similar answers found within stackoverflow but no luck. How can I correctly use interpolation inside the ngStyle for background-image?

This is the code I've use:

```
<div mat-card-avatar class="header-image" ngStyle = "{'background-image': 'url(' + {{cardData.image}} + ')'}"></div>
```

I am getting Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{'background-image': 'url(' + ../../assets/image/photo.png + ')'}' at .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use interpolation inside `ngStyle`, you have to use `[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + cardData.image + ')'}"`

Try like this:

```
<div mat-card-avatar class="header-image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + cardData.image + ')'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your ngStyle attributes in square brackets:

```
[ngStyle]="...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngStyle]="'{background-image: url(' + {{cardData.image}} + ')}'"
```

unsure if its even possible, however this would be correct for the quote marks